# How can create a similar block of consecutive roadmap items in only with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, adaptive-design

Suppose there is such a block of consecutive elements. How can this be rendered in pure HTML and CSS? Is this possible on flexbox or is it done differently? It is also necessary that this block of elements be adaptive, and when the screen is reduced, the blocks move down one under the other.

[image: roadmap image]

Comment: This would be a lot of work, I would opt for a much simpler, vertical diagram